# Need excel formula to sum the salaries per month for each position

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that counts how many employees there are for each position in each month but now i want to get the sum of each employees monthly salary for the positions in each month. Here is the formula i am using for counting portion.I want a formula that instead of counting how many employees there are for each position in each month, i want the monthly salaries instead

```
=+COUNTIFS(
    'Employee Census Report'!$O$2:$O$412, "<=" & 'Headcount Database'!F$4,
    'Employee Census Report'!$P$2:$P$412, "=" & "n/a",
    'Employee Census Report'!$Q$2:$Q$412, "=" & 'Headcount Database'!$E174,
    'Employee Census Report'!$G$2:$G$412, "=" & 'Headcount Database'!$E$172
) +
    COUNTIFS(
        'Employee Census Report'!$O$2:$O$412, "<=" & 'Headcount Database'!F$4,
        'Employee Census Report'!$P$2:$P$412, ">" & F$4,
        'Employee Census Report'!$Q$2:$Q$412, "=" & 'Headcount Database'!$E174,
        'Employee Census Report'!$G$2:$G$412, "=" & 'Headcount Database'!$E$172
    )
```

[Headcount Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ENQ.png)

Below is the tab where the data comes from
[employee Census Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz2N5.png)

....................................

Comment: So do check out that 'family" of functions: countifs, sumifs, averageifs, maxifs, minifs - all so useful with similar logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is taking the count under the conditions, and you're trying to get the sum under the same conditions, I would change it to a sumifs and simply add the sum field in the first section of the previous formula.

`=+SUMIFS('Employee Census Report'!$N$2:$N$412,'Employee Census Report'!$O$2:$O$412,"<="&'Headcount Database'!F$4,'Employee Census Report'!$P$2:$P$412,"="&"n/a",'Employee Census Report'!$Q$2:$Q$412,"="&'Headcount Database'!$E174,'Employee Census Report'!$G$2:$G$412,"="&'Headcount Database'!$E$172) + SUMIFS('Employee Census Report'!$N$2:$N$412,'Employee Census Report'!$O$2:$O$412,"<="&'Headcount Database'!F$4,'Employee Census Report'!$P$2:$P$412,">"&F$4,'Employee Census Report'!$Q$2:$Q$412,"="&'Headcount Database'!$E174,'Employee Census Report'!$G$2:$G$412,"="&'Headcount Database'!$E$172)`

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and clarity sake, let's assume your per employee salary data in in `"Monthly Salary"` range and your employment dates in `"Hire Date"` and `"Term Date"` (all dates are date values, not text strings). Also we need a field that can identify the employee, let's say `"Empl ID"`.

Then for employee with id `xxx`, the salary data for a given date range between `d0` and `d1` (both `d0` and `d1` must be date values), can be retrieved using either of two methods:

`= SUMPRODUCT ( Monthly Salary, Empl ID = xxx, --(Hire Date < d0), --(Term Date > d1) )`

or

`= FILTER ( Monthly Salary, (Empl ID = xxx) * (--(Hire Date < d0)) * (--(Term Date > d1)) )`

To get the sum of all salaries, just drop `Empl ID = xxx`

To get sums of smaller categories, add a category instead of `Empl ID = xxx`. E.g. `"Dept = "RnD"`.

Note that `SUMPRODUCT()` can only return numbers (in our example, salaries). `FILTER()` can return numbers or strings.